# How to get part of the string from an array element, and insert it into another array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array which returns something like this:

```
[44] => 165,text:Where is this city:,photo:c157,correct:0,answers:[{text:Pery.,correct:true},{text:Cuba.,correct:false},{text:Brazil.,correct:false}]},{
```

I would like to get all the numbers from the beginning of the string until the first occurrence of a comma in the array element value. In this case that would be number 165 and I want to place that number in another array named $newQuesitons as key questionID

Next part will be to get the string after the first occurrence of : until the next occurrence of : and add it into the same array ($newQuestions) as key question.

Next part will be the photo:, that is I need to get the string after the photo: until the next occurrence of  the comma, in this case peace of the string extracted will be c157.

I would like to add that as new key named photo in the array $newQuestions

Comment: good to hear.what you have tried so for?

Comment: I don't know how to search for a part of the value of an array key.

Comment: If you can tell me how can I get all the numbers from the start of the array value until the first occurrence of a comma I think I can find my way from there on

Comment: Read up on regular expressions.  After that, go here: https://regex101.com/  It's a great learning tool for what you want to do.  And after that you'll feel much better that you learned how to do this by your own merit vs. someone just writing it up for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be able to help you

```
<?php
 $input =  '165,text:Where is this city:,photo:c157,correct:0';

//define our new array
$newQuestions = Array();
//first part states we need to get all the numbers from the beginning of     the string until the first occurence of a ',' as this is our array key
//$arrayKey[0] is our arrayKey
$arrayKey = explode(',',$input);

//second part requires us to loop through the array and split up the strings by comma and colon
foreach($arrayKey as $data){
//split each text into 2 by the colon
    $item = explode(':',$data);
    //we are only interested in items that have a colon in them, if we split it and the input has no colon, the count would be 0, so this check is used to ignore those
    if(count($item) > 0) {
        //now we can build our array
        $newQuestions[$arrayKey[0]][$item[0]] = $item[1];
    }

}
//output array
print_r($newQuestions);

?>
```

I don't fully understand the inputted array so the code above will most likely have to be tweaked, but atleast it gives you some logic to go from.

The output of this was: `Array ( [165] => Array ( [165] => [text] => Where is this city [photo] => c157 [correct] => 0 ) )`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I feel that I will get lost during the tweaking. I will try to use the solution with string manipulation and I will also see what I can use from your code. Thanks again.

Comment: The tweaking is just on the input, I believe you are using a 2D array for your input. This code should still work but might fail when it comes to reading inside the array of "answers". Have a play around with it anyways. I'll check back later and see how you are getting on

Answer (score 1):

I get my own solution, at least for the part of the problem. I manage to get the questionID using the following code:

```
$newQuestions = array();

foreach ($arrQuestions as $key => $question) {
    $substring = substr($question, 0, strpos($question, ','));
        $newQuestions[]['questionID'] = $substring;  
}
```

I am now trying to do the same thing for the question part. I will update this code in case that someone else may have similar task to accomplish.

Comment: I suggest removing this and putting it inside the question you asked as it's most likely to be seen there.